# EF6 ToListAsync does not run async but blocks the thread

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, ef-database-first

To increase my page performance I wanted to run a few queries asynchronously.
I upgraded to EF6 because it natively supports this feature by exposing async methods.
I couldn't get the queries to fire simultaneously so i boiled my code down to this simple example :

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start(); 
var dummy = context.Set<CA_Event_Person>().Take(200).ToListAsync();
sw.Stop();
Logger.Debug("attempt nr 1 : " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
var result = await dummy;
```

My exception was that the stopwatch with instantly stop since i'm doing the await at a later point. 
My logger however says that 5000 milliseconds have passed on the stopwatch meaning the call was performed synchronous instead of asynchronous.
Anyone got some insight in the why or what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: What database is behind EF?  Because, for example, the SQL Compact bits don't support async so would block.

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone got some insight in the why or what I could be doing wrong?

Is this the first call into EF in the application? Could you be timing the one-off building of the internal representation of the EF model?

With a more complex EF model there is significant overhead on the first call. But this is a one off (per app domain) cost.

Better to time a number of calls (and then throw away the shortest and longest times).

Comment: I found that suggestion as well but no it's not the first call in my request.

Comment: Also , depending on the size of my take the duration increases or decrease. I also had a timer to time my await line and that timer had like 1 ms duration.

Comment: Do you get the same thing if you use a `DbSet<T>` property in the context? (Without a (short) re-create there will be a lot of guessing.)

Comment: Just tried the DBSet property and it gave the same result. I'll try to create a small project to simulate the problem but not having a public sql server might make thinks difficult :)

Comment: @Kristof Don't need to provide a DB: just a little script to create the structure and some data.

Comment: Whlie creating my demo project it seems you where spot on with your answer, the context generation was the bigest part of the query. It wasn't the first database call but it is the first database call on that context(i have multiple). After the first toListAsync the next tasks get generated within 1 ms. I did some further research and apparantly an async method will only return itself as a task after the first await statement(which is kinda weird but does explain this behaviour)